Kubernetes connection refused when trying to make http request to pod
I have two dotnet services that I'm trying to deploy to my local kubernetes (I'm using Docker Desktop on Windows) - commands service and platforms service. My deployment files are
platforms-service-depl.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platforms-service-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: platformservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platformservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: platformservice
          image: mj97/platformservice:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platform-clusterip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: platformservice
  ports:
    - name: platformservice
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080

commands-service-depl.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: commands-service-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: commandservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: commandservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: commandservice
          image: mj97/commandservice:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: command-clusterip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: commandservice
  ports:
    - name: commandservice
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080

and my ingress-service.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: course.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/platforms
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: platform-clusterip-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api/commands/platforms
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: command-clusterip-service
                port:
                  number: 80

Now when I'm trying to make http request to my api endpoint all I get is
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to course.com port 80 after 2043 ms: Connection refused

I have also modified my hosts file by adding 127.0.0.1 course.com.
Running netstat -ntlp in the platforms service pod I get
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/dotnet

I have tried doing curl requests directly to pod ip and cluster ip service ip but I get time outs. I also tried recreating deploys and cluster ip services in hopes that I've missed something and just didn't recreate them but no luck. I thought that my ports configurations are ok.

I got it working. What was missing was an ingress controller https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/. After running kubectl apply command from that link my ingress is working and I can hit api endpoints.
